# Select second element that is after first one

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have 2 `div`s in code under 1 `li`. I need to select second one:

```
<li>
 <div id='1'>Stable Text</div>
 <div>Unstable Text</div>
</li>
```

I can find only first one using text's name, as its stable. But I need second one.
using `xpath` with `//li/div[2]` will not work because place of this data is not stable.

Comment: yes, in first div its always same, so I can find it, in second one it is changing everytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `following-sibling`.

```
//div[text() = 'Stable Text']/following-sibling::div
```

You can have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp) for more information.

Comment: i can't find li by position, so without it I can't find second div in li, I mentioned it. I only can find 1st div

Comment: @EminMastizada now I get it, sorry about that, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

you can try using a `cssSelector` as well,

```
li > div#1 + div
```

Here **'+'** is used to locate following sibling..[you can refer this for more info on selectors](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2010/01/selenium-totw-css-selectors-in-selenium-demystified/).